# Syntax error: ' | ' unexpected in aws s3 upload script

Tags: android, amazon-s3, syntax-error

Hi I tried to upload video on my aws s3 cloud account. I am using one script which is provided by aws. And using that I am able to upload video on aws from my pc. But when I tried same thing on cross platform which is running on qualcomm and android same script giving me error "syntax error: '|' unexpected" . Same script I also tried to run other platform like 'TI' platform on that also it was running fine. Is there any problem with android sdk ??

In same script pipe('|') symbol used as so many places but at one particular line only it is showing error.

I put that part of code where its showing me error.

```
echo "Before Pipe Symbol...\n"
p=$(cat <<POLICY | openssl base64
{ "expiration": "${expdate}T12:00:00.000Z",
"conditions": [
{"acl": "$acl" },
{"bucket": "$bucket" },
["starts-with", "\$key", ""],
["starts-with", "\$content-type", ""],
["content-length-range", 1, `busybox ls -l "$srcfile" | busybox awk     '{print $5}' | busybox head -1`],
{"content-md5": "$md5" },
{"x-amz-date": "$date" },
{"x-amz-credential":   "$aws_ak/$expdate_s/$region/$service/aws4_request" },
{"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" },
{"x-amz-security-token": "$sessiontoken" }
]
}
POLICY
)
echo "After Pipe Symbol...\n"
```

In this code 2nd line creating error.

How can i resolve this error? Is there any other thing which i can use instead of this pipe('|') symbol.

Comment: This doesn't look like it has anything to do with the Android SDK. It looks like a Bash script, not an Android app. How are you running this on an Android device exactly?

Comment: I am running like "sh <script_name>" and I tried "./<scrip_name>" also.

Comment: You could also try `p=$(openssl base64 <<POLICY` ... it seems like that should have the same net effect.  Using `cat` and the pipe seems unnecessary, though it's not obvious why it doesn't work as written... though your shell is possibly `dash`, and not `bash`, which might explain this problem.

Comment: `p=$(openssl base64 <<POLICY`  using this line it's worked. Thank you very much Michael...:) @Michael-sqlbot